# cant find my error in my html code, for a javascript quiz

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, show

I have placed my website in my dropbox so you can see my problem. What I am trying to do is, when you click the image next to tennis or squash it turns red (false.png) and when they click badminton it turns green (true.png), which then makes the next question appear. At the moment only the next question appears and I'm having trouble with the image changing.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13722201/website/quiz.html

Please could you poke around in the source code and figure it out because I'm baffled.

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('badminton-answer').setAttribute('src', 'images/true.png'" href="javascript:toggle();">
  <img id="badminton-answer" border="0" alt="" src="images/answer.png" width="290" height="60"/>
</a>
```

the javascript showing/ hiding div id="next"

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("next");

if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
}
```

}

```
</script>
```

Comment: Consider jsfiddle.net instead, or post a minimal, breaking example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `onclick` handlers contain this code:

```
document.answer.src='images/false.png'
```

`document` doesn't have an `answer` property.  The best way to manipulate the DOM in JavaScript is to assign your HTML element a unique ID:

```
<img id="tennis-answer" alt="" src="images/answer.png" width="290" height="60"/>
```

If an element has a unique ID, then you can get a reference to it and modify the element:

```
document.getElementById('tennis-answer')
        .setAttribute('src', 'images/false.png');
```

Here's how it all looks together for the Badminton answer:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('badminton-answer').setAttribute('src', 'images/true.png'" href="javascript:toggle();">
  <img id="badminton-answer" border="0" alt="" src="images/answer.png" width="290" height="60"/>
</a>
```

Comment: thankyou, but im only just starting to learn javascript. not to seem stupid but could you possibly show me how it would fit in please.

Comment: i have put it in but still no colour change sorry to bother you with such a beginners question. its updated in the drop box too.

Comment: Looks like an extra `}` now.  A useful JavaScript development technique is to install and run developer tools that let you know when you get a runtime error and on which line the error is.  Firebug is nice for Firefox, and Chrome and IE have pretty good developer tools as well (hit F12 to bring them up)

Comment: thanks for showing me that the console says that i have an error on line 78 <img id="badminton-answer" border="0" alt="" src="images/answer.png" width="290" height="60"/>
      Message= quiz.html:78Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: figured it out thankyou.   .setAttribute('src', 'images/true.png'" needed a ) before the " at the end

Answer (score 0):

All three images have the same id (answer). They should probably have unique IDs. Also, I'd put the image flipping code into a function and call the function on click instead of putting the code in the onclick of the button.